# Longest common subsequence alternative

Tags: javascript

I would like to ask you about to any alternatives for LCS algorithm.

I have an implemention of LCS algorithm in javascript, and it works like below

```
string_A: 'hello from london sample'
string_B: 'londons'
result: 'londons'
```

but I am looking for algorithm which shows only common part of two strings, so result from `function(string_A, string_B)` should be `london`.

Comment: where is your code??

Comment: Are you looking for longest common substring ?

Comment: [example implementation of LCS](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Longest_common_subsequence#JavaScript)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this algorithm seems a bit **too specific** to just capture common substring strictly. It is likely more flexible than your situation requires. It captures all symbols from `string_A` that take place in the same order in `string_B`, no matter if there are other symbols between:

```
LCS( 'hello from london sample', 'hfls' ); // returns 'hlfs'
LCS( 'hello from london sample', 'from amazing london' ); // returns 'from london'
```

To extract just strictly the common part, the solution can be quite obvious. Just test all possible substrings of `string_B` to be included in `string_A`, starting from the longest. So I suggest my own version:

```
function LCSS( a, b ) {
    let len = b.length, originalLen = b.length;
    do {
        for ( let i = 0; i <= originalLen - len; i++ ) {
            let needle = b.substr( i, len );
            if ( a.indexOf( needle ) !== -1 ) return needle;
        }
    } while ( len-- > 0 );
    return false;
}
```

Try it working: http://codepen.io/pttsky/pen/rjbOza

Comment: would be ok but 

`LCSS( "from me to you", "me you" )` should return `me you` and for
`LCSS( "from me to youuuuu", "me you" )` should return `me you` and for
`LCSS( "from me to yo1u", "me you" )`