# Longest sequence of number in two arrays

Tags: javascript, compare

I have two array that initialize in random number between 0-9
I need to find the longest same sequence that exist in both of them.

For example

```
var arrFirst = [8,5,3,0,3,1,8,2,8,7,3,5,4,0,8,5,7,3,1]
var arrSecond = [8,5,4,0,2,9,4,3,6,9,2,3,1,8,2,8,7,3,3]
```

The result array need to contain the longest sequence that appear in both array

```
var arrResult = [3,1,8,2,8,7,3]
```

In this example we have sequence right on start [8, 5] but it's not the longest one.

Could you please provide some code that would help me?

Thanx

Comment: What's the question? Are you requesting code?

Comment: what do you mean by "longest same sequence"?

Comment: What went wrong when you tried?

Comment: where is your tried code

Comment: both array have same number of value

Comment: paste your code for generating random number between 0-9 and store in arrray

Comment: i change the example so it would be clear, At the start of both array i  have 8, 5 - This is "sequence" but it's not the longest.

Comment: Longest same sequence or Longest common sequence?? sequence or substring? please clarify

Comment: Please make an attempt first http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/longest-common-subsequence/ https://gist.github.com/alexishacks/725df6db4432cd29cd43 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42267760/longest-common-subsequence-alternative

Comment: This is a pretty common code problem used for interviews. Surely you don't want us to solve this for you? You aren't doing yourself any favors.

Comment: Longest same sequence, I edit the Post. My bad.

Comment: if you dont provide any update after comment a down-vote for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check ech element of `array1` with every element of `array2` and go on with checking the elements with a `while` loop with a counter and for each array an offset for the index.

Later check if the length of the found same elements is greater or equal to the last found array and either replace the result set with the new longer one or append, if equal to the result set.

```js
var array1 = [8, 5, 3, 0, 3, 1, 8, 2, 8, 7, 3, 5, 4, 0, 8, 5, 7, 3, 1],
    array2 = [1, 8, 4, 0, 2, 9, 4, 3, 6, 9, 2, 3, 1, 8, 2, 8, 7, 3, 3],
    result = array1.reduce(function (r, _, i, a) {
        array2.forEach(function (__, j, b) {
            var k = 0,
                temp = [];

            while ((i + k) in a && (j + k) in b && a[i + k] === b[j + k]) {
                temp.push(a[i + k]);
                k++;
            }
            if (!r.length || temp.length > r[0].length) {
                r = [temp];
                return;
            }
            if (temp.length === r[0].length) {
                r.push(temp);
            }
        });
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Its not working for `arr1=[8, 5, 3]` and `arr2=[1, 8, 3]`

Comment: @vivek, nice catch, i added some checks to take only existent indices for checking.

Comment: why not find all the combinations?

Comment: it does, but it filters only the longest ones with the two `if`s

Answer (score 1):

Pseudo code:

```
1)create two more arrays for longest sequence and another one for running sequence
2)Start looking for matches between 2 original arrays
3)Keep current sequence in runningSequence array
4)check if arrays match
  5)if so check if length of running sequence is longer than theLongestSequence array
    6)If so, replace the longestSequenceArray content with runningSequence array and keep going
    7)if not, proceed to next char position
8)Repeat until all chars in original arrays are processed by going back to step 4
9)Print Longest array content
```

It is your responsibility to write to code for above logic.

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this to search maximum length exist in second array

```js
var arrFirst = [8,5,3,0,3,1,8,2,8,7,3,5,4,0,8,5,7,3,1];
var arrSecond = [8,5,4,0,2,9,4,3,6,9,2,3,1,8,2,8,7,3,3];
var firstStr = arrFirst.join("");
var secondStr = arrSecond.join("");
var combinations = getCombination(firstStr);
combinations = combinations.sort(function(a, b){
  return b.length - a.length;
});
for(var i in combinations){
  if(secondStr.indexOf(combinations[i]) !== -1){
    console.log(combinations[i]+" found with length : "+combinations[i].length);
    console.log(combinations[i].split(""));
    break;
  }
}

function getCombination(str) {
    var fn = function(active, rest, a) {
        if (!active && !rest)
            return;
        if (!rest) {
            if(firstStr.search(active) !== -1){
              a.push(active);
            }
        } else {
            fn(active + rest[0], rest.slice(1), a);
            fn(active, rest.slice(1), a);
        }
        return a;
    }
    return fn("", str, []);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting the solution of this task written in C++ in case somebody needs it.

```
void clear(int *ar, int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        ar[i] = 0;
    }
}

void copy(int*first, int *second, int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        first[i] = second[i];
    }
}

int main() {

    int ar_1[] = { 8,5,3,0,3,1,8,2,8,7,3,5,4,0,8,5,7,3,1 };
    int ar_2[] = { 8,5,4,0,2,9,4,3,6,9,2,3,1,8,2,8,7,3,3 };

    const int arr_size = sizeof(ar_1) / sizeof(int);

    int arr_longest[arr_size] = { 0 };
    int sequence_counter = 0;

    int arr_temp[arr_size] = { 0 };
    int temp_counter = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < arr_size; i++)
    {
        bool match = false;
        int inner_counter = 0;

        for (int k = 0; k < arr_size; k++)
        {
            if (match)
            {
                if (ar_1[++inner_counter] == ar_2[k])
                {
                    arr_temp[temp_counter++] = ar_2[k];
                }
                else
                {
                    if (temp_counter > sequence_counter)
                    {
                        sequence_counter = temp_counter;
                        copy(arr_longest, arr_temp, arr_size);
                    }

                    clear(arr_temp, arr_size);
                    temp_counter = 0;
                    match = false;
                }
            }
            else if (ar_1[i] == ar_2[k])
            {
                arr_temp[temp_counter++] = ar_1[i];
                inner_counter = i;
                match = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```